# Результаты выполнения CompareTo

Tags: c#

Почему в случае

```
string s1 = "раз два три";
string s2 = "раз";
int result;

result = s1.CompareTo(s2);

Console.WriteLine(result);
```

в результате получаю 1.

А в случае

```
string s1 = "раз два три";
string s2 = "три";
int result;

result = s1.CompareTo(s2);

Console.WriteLine(result);
```

в результате получаю -1.

Почему во втором случае отрицательное значение?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Потому что строки сравниваются лексикографически:

- сначала сравниваются первые символы, если они не равны, возвращается результат
- затем сравниваются вторые символ, если они не равны, возвращается результат
- и т. д. до конца одной из строк. если начала совпадают, более длинная строка считается больше
- в противном случае строки совпадают и значит равны

В первом случае сравнение идёт до конца первой строки, поскольку она длиннее, получаете ответ «больше». Во втором случае сравнение останавливается на первом символе, `'р' < 'т'`, поэтому первая строка считается «меньше».